# swift map range: unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: swift

I would like to map a range into an array.  The swift compiler 5.2 says it is too complex to type-check.  It doesn't look like it should be; it seems pretty simple.  I've tried adding explicit types on the constants and the result of the map, but beyond being verbose and ugly, it did not help.  Is it possible to force the compiler to type-check this (basically, not give up)?  Is swift really not able to type-check this?  Why is that and what can I do about it?  Code is below.  Here is a [repl](https://repl.it/repls/SoupyUtilizedCarrier). Thanks for your help.

```swift
let p = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

let pExact = 0.8
let pOvershoot = 0.1
let pUndershoot = 0.1

func move(_ p: [Double], _ U: Int) -> [Double] {
    let n = p.count
    let q: [Double] = (0...n-1).map {i in 
        p[(i - (U + 1) + n) % n] * pUndershoot 
      + p[(i - U + n)       % n] * pExact 
      + p[(i - (U - 1) + n) % n] * pOvershoot
    }
    return q
}

print(move(p, 1))
```

So a little more info, it seems it has to do with the range map. I can pull out the other logic and it compiles and runs fine.

```swift
let p = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

let pExact = 0.8
let pOvershoot = 0.1
let pUndershoot = 0.1

let n = p.count
let i = 1
let U = 1
let q = p[(i - (U + 1) + n) % n] * pUndershoot 
        + p[(i - U + n)       % n] * pExact 
        + p[(i - (U - 1) + n) % n] * pOvershoot


print(q)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why the compiler has trouble doing type inference here, but typing the closure parameter is enough to fix it for me:

```
let p = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

let pExact = 0.8
let pOvershoot = 0.1
let pUndershoot = 0.1

func move(_ p: [Double], _ U: Int) -> [Double] {
    let n = p.count
    let q: [Double] = (0...n-1).map { (i: Int) in 
        p[(i - (U + 1) + n) % n] * pUndershoot 
      + p[(i - U + n)       % n] * pExact 
      + p[(i - (U - 1) + n) % n] * pOvershoot
    }
    return q
}

print(move(p, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift has trouble with `+`. I don't recommend this at all, but if you disambiguate by not using it, you can use implicit typing.

```swift
infix operator ➕: AdditionPrecedence

extension Double {
  static func ➕ (_ double0: Self, _ double1: Self) -> Self {
    double0 + double1
  }
}

func move(_ p: [Double], _ U: Int) -> [Double] {
  let n = p.count
  let q = (0...n-1).map { i in
    p[(i - (U + 1) + n) % n] * pUndershoot
    ➕ p[(i - U + n)       % n] * pExact
    ➕ p[(i - (U - 1) + n) % n] * pOvershoot
  }
  return q
}
```

Explicit types are the fastest fix, as shown by the other answers. But Accelerate or even just SIMD may be a better match for your problem.

```swift
import simd

func move(_ p: [Double], _ U: Int) -> [Double] {
  let n = p.count
  return (0..<n).map { i in
    dot(
      SIMD3(
        (-1...1).map { p[(i - (U + $0) + n) % n] }
      ),
      [pUndershoot, pExact, pOvershoot]
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, once I understood it was the map function that was ambiguous, I added a type specifier to the argument; the lambda takes an Int and returns a Double, `(i:Int) -> Double`.  This compiled and ran correctly;

```swift
let p = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

let pExact = 0.8
let pOvershoot = 0.1
let pUndershoot = 0.1

func move(_ p: [Double], _ U: Int) -> [Double] {
    let n = p.count
    let q: [Double] = (0...(n-1)).map {(i:Int) -> Double in 
        p[(i - (U + 1) + n) % n] * pUndershoot 
      + p[(i - U + n)       % n] * pExact 
      + p[(i - (U - 1) + n) % n] * pOvershoot
    }
    return q
}

print(move(p, 1))
```